# Why is search bar changing position of headers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an HTML/CSS/JS project with a search bar and a header. When the search bar is activated/deactivated (clicked on), it changes the position of my headers. How can I fix this issue and keep the headers in the same position? Thanks a lot!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && filter != "") {//change here
            li[i].style.display = "";
            li[i].style.visibility = "visible";//change here
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
   background-image: url('paperforrite-removebg-preview.png');
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 558px;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
<ul id="myUL" style="visibility: hidden">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<h1><center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 100px; color: #000000;">Some text here</center></h1>
<br>
<br>
<h2><center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #000000;">Some text here</center></h2>
```

Comment: Don't game the SO system, please. Also don't use line breaks for formatting. Margin and padding, applied via CSS classes, are the tools for that.

Comment: [Why should line breaks *not* be used? (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#accessibility_concerns)

Comment: Sorry, I was not intending to game the SO system. I added extra words because the SO system would not let me post my question without adding extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add  `position: absolute;` to the #myUl css tag, like shown below.

Your current ul tag is part of the flow and thus push everything down.

At first, it pushes everything down because it has `visibility: hidden`, which renders the ul with its height/width.

Then, when you type in the search bar, your javascript kicks in, which in turn hides the block with display: none, removing its block property and not making it render the height/width.

If you wish to keep the block behavior (push down the header), just switch the `visibility: hidden` to `display: none` in the ul html.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && filter != "") {//change here
            li[i].style.display = "";
            li[i].style.visibility = "visible";//change here
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
   background-image: url('paperforrite-removebg-preview.png');
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 558px;
  position: absolute;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
<ul id="myUL" style="visibility: hidden">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<h1><center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 100px; color: #000000;">Some text here</center></h1>
<br>
<br>
<h2><center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #000000;">Some text here</center></h2>
```